# Godot - Untarget dead enemy

Tags: godot, gdscript

So I want to set my `_target_node` to null when an enemy dies.

Here how I target an enemy:
in my `player.gd` I have:

```
var _target_node: Node = null

func handle_target_lock():
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("target_lock"):
        if _target_node:
            _target_node = null
        else:
            var enemies: Array = get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("Enemy")

            if enemies.size() > 0:
                _target_node = enemies[0]

    if _target_node:
        look_at(_target_node.global_transform.origin, Vector3.UP)
```

Problem is, when an enemy dies, `_target_node` is now referencing a deleted instance.

My enemy node emits a signal `died` when its hp is 0, but I don't know how to use this information to notify my player.

How do I notify the player that the targeted enemy is dead and `_target_node` should be set to null?

Godot version 3.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are saying there is a died signal so you could connect to it's die signal, when it is targeted:

```
if Input.is_action_just_pressed("target_lock"):
    if _target_node:
         #"died" should be renamed to your signal name!
        _target_node.disconnect("died",self, "on_target_died") # disconnect if you switch the target
        _target_node = null
    else:
        var enemies: Array = get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("Enemy")

        if enemies.size() > 0:
            _target_node = enemies[0]
            #"died" should be renamed to your signal name!
            _target_node.connect("died",self, "on_target_died")

func on_target_died():
    _target_node = null
```

Edit: It could help to pass the enemy as a parameter in the died signal so you can check, if the event was really fired from the enemy that is currently targeted. Otherwise there could be the chance, the player is still connected to the wrong enemy while switching targets

Answer (score 1):

> Problem is, when an enemy dies, _target_node is now referencing a deleted instance.

You can check for that:

```
if is_instance_valid(_target_node):
```

On the other hand, this form:

```
if _target_node:
```

Is checking if the variable is not zeroed. For an `Object` type (such as `Node`) it is checking if the variable is not set to `null`. However you can free `Node`s while there are still references to them. *As you might now, `Node` is not reference counted (it does not extend `Reference`), instead you free them manually with `free` or `queue_free`.* When a `Node` is freed, Godot does not automatically turn the references that point to it into `null`, instead they become invalid references. We use `is_instance_valid` to check for that.